# Magento 2 - Error: pub/media/wysiwyg is not under storage root path

Tags: magento2, admin, static-block, wysiwyg

I facing this error when uploading images in static blocks.

Can anyone suggest me, why is this happen?

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: Yes i got this error : pub/media/wysiwyg is not under storage root path.

Comment: May be, This can help you : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13929

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the new module, Then add below code in your module di.xml

> /app/code/Vendor/Mymodule/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryResolver"
                type="Vendor\Mymodule\App\Filesystem\DirectoryResolver"/>
</config>
```

Now Create the file,

> Vendor\Mymodule\App\Filesystem\DirectoryResolver.php

and add below code in the file:

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Mymodule\App\Filesystem\DirectoryResolver;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

/**
 * Magento directories resolver.
 */
class DirectoryResolver 
{
    /**
     * @var DirectoryList
     */
    private $directoryList;

    /**
     * @param DirectoryList $directoryList
     */
    public function __construct(DirectoryList $directoryList)
    {
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
    }

    /**
     * Validate path.
     *
     * Gets real path for directory provided in parameters and compares it with specified root directory.
     * Will return TRUE if real path of provided value contains root directory path and FALSE if not.
     * Throws the \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException in case when directory path is absent
     * in Directories configuration.
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $directoryConfig
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException
     */
    public function validatePath($path, $directoryConfig = DirectoryList::MEDIA)
    {
        $realPath = realpath($path);
        /**
         * Since media directory is a symlink, need to run both paths through realpath in order for the comparison to
         * work.
         * The proper fix for this should involve a STORE > Configuration setting where an admin can choose whether to
         * allow symlinked directories.
         */
        $root = realpath($this->directoryList->getPath($directoryConfig));
        // END EDIT

        return strpos($realPath, $root) === 0;
    }
}
```

Please create the require file for module registration.php and **module.xml**

Answer (score 0):

> **Run Below Command and check it**

```
php bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 0

php bin/magento c:f
```

> **If your Folder is not showing than create below code:**

For security purposes, Magento provides Media Gallery access to contents in specific folders. The configuration path system/media_storage_configuration/media_storage/allowed_resource/media_gallery_image_folders in config.xml is used to define “Media Gallery Allowed” folders

By default, Magento allows Media Gallery access to the following two directories under /pub/media:

- catalog/category
- wysiwyg

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <system>
            <media_storage_configuration>
                <allowed_resources>
                    <catalog_images_folder>catalog</catalog_images_folder> <!-- Show Catalog Folder -->
                    <media_gallery_image_folders>
                        <category_image_folder>catalog/category</category_image_folder> <!--  Show Sub Catalog Folder -->
                        <my_image_folder>custom_folder_name</my_image_folder>
                        <my_catalog_image_folder>catalog/custom_folder_name</my_catalog_image_folder>
                    </media_gallery_image_folders>
                </allowed_resources>
            </media_storage_configuration>
        </system>
    </default>
</config>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***